Обрезка части строки
Есть файл со строками вида:
*D    ru.test
* R   fd.dddd
*R cc.fff.ff

Как преобразовать строки, чтобы на выходе получилось
ru.test
fd.dddd
cc.fff.ff


Так:
awk '{print $NF}' ваш_файл

